# How to use a common data bound header and footer with ngView?

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing a complex business application using AngularJs.

I want to have common data bound and control elements outside of the ngView block for purposes such as displaying general notifications in the footer area, error messages in the header area, a dynamic menu that morphs contextually based on which view is active in the header area, a search box in the menu that triggers a new view with search results, login controls etc.

This is in addition to the main "working area" on the page where the ngView directive is used and my (mostly) CRUD operations will be needed.

I've come across various information related to this but much of it assumes static header and footer which is not what I'm after.

Can I have an ngView directive and still manage the rest of the page as though I wasn't using ngView with a controller declared for the header (if that makes any sense?) or should I be ditching ngView entirely but keep ngRoute and try to do all this through directives or includes?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, may be a parent controller could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is as you say: Top and bottom have controllers; content is `ng-view`. From an example [project](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) of mine:

```
<body>
    <div ... x-ng-controller="app/main/NavbarCtrl"
        x-ng-include="'virtual-template/navbar.html'"></div>

    <div class="container">
        <div x-ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So there is a controller and a template for the header (I have no footer, but the logic is the same). Then, in a separate section goes the `ng-view`. The navbar in my case contains a dynamic menu, but any dynamic content is possible.

Comment: Thank you Nikos, so you mean here: https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy/blob/master/WebContent/app.html#L20-L24 ?  Does your NavBarCtrl react to changes in the route as well?

Comment: Yes that is the file; and yes the navbar reacts: it highlights the current route (simple but still a reaction - see the [template](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy/blob/master/WebContent/scripts/app/main/navbar.html) where it says `<li x-ng-repeat="menuEntry in menuEntries" x-ng-class="{active: isActive(menuEntry)}">`).